# Ingresar Picaso lib dentro de un listview sin adaptador

Tags: android, json, picasso

Buenas, estoy haciendo una consulta a un array json, todo funciona de maravillas, el codigo es simple y ligero, el problema lo obtengo cuando deseo agregar una imagen a mi listview, ya que no me la muestra.

tengo este fragmento de codigo:

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        tab_bancos.this, BancoList,
                        R.layout.lista_bancos, new String[]{"logo","bank", "accholder",
                        "id", "account"}, new int[]{
                        R.id.bankimg,R.id.bankname,
                        R.id.bankacch, R.id.bankaccid, R.id.accnumber});

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Quiero saber si puedo usar picasso para ingresar la imagen, en otras pruebas este codigo me ha funcionado bien:

```
    pruebitalogo = (CircleImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.pruebitaimg);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://www.asturscore.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Logan.jpeg").into(R.id.pruebitalogo);
```

Ahora bien, lo que quiero es sustituir en mi codigo "logo" y que me acepte el url y me llene el objeto R.id.bankimg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta la encontre luego de investigar un poco, aqui la dejo en caso de que alguien tenga la misma duda:

No se puede usar picasso directamente en el adaptador, por lo que solo hay que modificarlo, se crea una clase llamada MyAdapter que extienda de SimpleAdapter:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
  // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
  View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

  // Then we get reference for Picasso
  ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
  if(img == null){
     img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageOrders);
     v.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
  }
  // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
  String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(TAG_IMAGE);
  // do Picasso
  Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(url).into(img);

  // return the view
  return v;
   }
}
```

Y luego llamamos a nuestro adaptador:

```
    ListView list= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    ListAdapter adapter = 
   new MyAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            orderList,
            R.layout.order_usa_row,
            new String[]{TAG_PRICE,TAG_TITLE,TAG_PSTATUS,TAG_PRICESYMBOL},
            new int[]{R.id.price,R.id.title,R.id.pstatus,R.id.symbol});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Aqui esta el link donde saque la respuesta, esta en ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118318/how-do-i-pass-picasso-into-listview-adapter